# Importing an interface. Cannot use namespace '' as a type

Tags: typescript

I'm import an interface:

```
import type custom from 'commonlib';
```

Here's how the interface is defined and exported:

custom.ts

```
export interface custom {
    one: string;
    two: string;
    three: boolean;
}
```

index.ts

```
export { custom } from './assets/custom';
```

When I try to use the interface like so:

```
let customObj: custom;
```

I get an error:

> Cannot use namespace 'custom' as a type.

If I change the import like so:

```
import {custom} from 'commonlib';
```

I get an error saying:

> 'custom' is a type and must be imported using a type-only import when
> 'preserveValueImports' and 'isolatedModules' are both enabled.

Should I remove `preserveValueImports` and `isolatedModules` from tsconfig.json or how do I solve this?

Comment: change it to `import type { custom } from 'commonlib';`

Comment: Thank you. If i had a dollar every time I get stuck with imports / exports...